# How to count number of occurrences per hour, including zeros from hours where nothing happened?

Tags: r, count, tidyverse

I have observational data of how often males and females feed. It includes the start and end time of the observation, and the exact time that males and females feed. Here is representative data...

```
feeding_data <- structure(list(Behavior = c("Male Feed", "Female Feed", "Female Feed", 
                                            "Male Feed", "Female Feed", "Female Feed", "Male Feed", "Female Feed", 
                                            "Female Feed", "Female Feed", "Male Feed", "Female Feed", "Female Feed", 
                                            "Female Feed", "Male Feed", "Female Feed", "Female Feed", "Male Feed", 
                                            "Female Feed", "Female Feed", "Female Feed", "Female Feed", "Female Feed", 
                                            "Male Feed", "Female Feed", "Female Feed", "Male Feed", "Male Feed", 
                                            "Female Feed", "Female Feed", "Female Feed", "Male Feed", "Female Feed", 
                                            "Female Feed", "Female Feed", "Male Feed", "Female Feed", "Male Feed", 
                                            "Female Feed", "Male Feed", "Female Feed", "Male Feed", "Female Feed", 
                                            "Male Feed", "Female Feed", "Female Feed", "Female Feed", "Male Feed", 
                                            "Male Feed"), Behavior_Number = 1:49, Time = c("7:00:00", "7:01:00", 
                                                                                           "7:02:00", "7:07:00", "7:17:00", "7:18:00", "7:18:00", "7:37:00", 
                                                                                           "7:37:00", "7:38:00", "7:57:00", "7:58:00", "7:59:00", "8:21:00", 
                                                                                           "8:21:00", "8:27:00", "8:28:00", "8:29:00", "8:46:00", "8:46:00", 
                                                                                           "8:59:00", "10:00:00", "10:00:00", "10:01:00", "10:11:00", "10:12:00", 
                                                                                           "10:34:00", "10:35:00", "10:35:00", "10:54:00", "10:54:00", "10:55:00", 
                                                                                           "11:24:00", "11:24:00", "11:24:00", "11:33:00", "11:33:00", "11:34:00", 
                                                                                           "11:42:00", "11:43:00", "11:56:00", "11:57:00", "12:13:00", "12:14:00", 
                                                                                           "12:16:00", "12:33:00", "12:33:00", "12:55:00", "12:56:00"), 
                               Start_Time = c("6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", 
                                              "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", 
                                              "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", 
                                              "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", 
                                              "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", 
                                              "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", 
                                              "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", 
                                              "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00", 
                                              "6:55:00", "6:55:00", "6:55:00"), End_Time = c("13:24:00", 
                                                                                             "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", 
                                                                                             "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", 
                                                                                             "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", 
                                                                                             "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", 
                                                                                             "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", 
                                                                                             "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", 
                                                                                             "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", 
                                                                                             "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", 
                                                                                             "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00", 
                                                                                             "13:24:00", "13:24:00", "13:24:00")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                       -49L))
```

When you look at the data, you can see that feedings don't take place in every hour. No feedings take place in the 6:00:00 - 7:00:00 hour, in the 9:00:00 - 10:00:00 hour, or in the 13:00:00 - 14:00:00 hour. Also, the first and last hours are often not complete, as they start and end at some point in the middle of the hour...

```
      Behavior Behavior_Number     Time Start_Time End_Time
1    Male Feed               1  7:00:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
2  Female Feed               2  7:01:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
3  Female Feed               3  7:02:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
4    Male Feed               4  7:07:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
5  Female Feed               5  7:17:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
6  Female Feed               6  7:18:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
7    Male Feed               7  7:18:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
8  Female Feed               8  7:37:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
9  Female Feed               9  7:37:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
10 Female Feed              10  7:38:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
11   Male Feed              11  7:57:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
12 Female Feed              12  7:58:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
13 Female Feed              13  7:59:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
14 Female Feed              14  8:21:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
15   Male Feed              15  8:21:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
16 Female Feed              16  8:27:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
17 Female Feed              17  8:28:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
18   Male Feed              18  8:29:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
19 Female Feed              19  8:46:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
20 Female Feed              20  8:46:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
21 Female Feed              21  8:59:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
22 Female Feed              22 10:00:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
23 Female Feed              23 10:00:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
24   Male Feed              24 10:01:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
25 Female Feed              25 10:11:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
26 Female Feed              26 10:12:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
27   Male Feed              27 10:34:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
28   Male Feed              28 10:35:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
29 Female Feed              29 10:35:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
30 Female Feed              30 10:54:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
31 Female Feed              31 10:54:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
32   Male Feed              32 10:55:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
33 Female Feed              33 11:24:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
34 Female Feed              34 11:24:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
35 Female Feed              35 11:24:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
36   Male Feed              36 11:33:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
37 Female Feed              37 11:33:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
38   Male Feed              38 11:34:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
39 Female Feed              39 11:42:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
40   Male Feed              40 11:43:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
41 Female Feed              41 11:56:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
42   Male Feed              42 11:57:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
43 Female Feed              43 12:13:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
44   Male Feed              44 12:14:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
45 Female Feed              45 12:16:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
46 Female Feed              46 12:33:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
47 Female Feed              47 12:33:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
48   Male Feed              48 12:55:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
49   Male Feed              49 12:56:00    6:55:00 13:24:00
```

I want to count up the total number of feedings that take place (ignoring sex) in each hour, even in the hours where no feedings take place, and also calculate how long that hour was. So for example, the 6:00:00 - 7:00:00 hour will only be 0:05:00 because that hour started at 6:55:00. So, my desired outcome is this...

```
      Hour Number_feeds duration
1  6:00:00            0 00:05:00
2  7:00:00           13 01:00:00
3  8:00:00            8 01:00:00
4  9:00:00            0 01:00:00
5 10:00:00           11 01:00:00
6 11:00:00           10 01:00:00
7 12:00:00            7 01:00:00
8 13:00:00            0 00:24:00
```

Using the count() function in dplyr only counts up the totals of hours where feeds took place, and ignores the hours where no feeds took place.

How can I achieve my desired outcome, preferably in the tidyverse?

Comment: If one or more feeds started at 6:55 what's the rationale for `Number_feeds` = 0?

Comment: @JonSpring Sorry, my notation wasn't clear enough. The "Time" column indicates the time that each feed takes place at, so the first feed doesn't take place until 7:00:00. So, no feeds took place in the 6:00:00 - 7:00:00 hour.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit convoluted, but you could do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

feeding_data %>%
  mutate(hour = as.numeric(str_extract(Time, "^\\d+"))) %>%
  group_by(hour) %>%
  summarise(count = n(), 
            Start = as.POSIXct(paste("2000-01-01", first(Start_Time))), 
            End = as.POSIXct(paste("2000-01-01", first(End_Time)))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(hour = lubridate::hour(first(Start)):lubridate::hour(first(End)),
           fill = list(count = 0)) %>%
  fill(Start, End, .direction = "downup") %>%
  mutate(hour = as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "GMT") + 
           lubridate::hours(hour)) %>%
  mutate(Start = pmax(Start, hour), 
         End = pmin(hour + lubridate::hours(1), End),
         duration = End - Start,
         hour = sub("^.* ", "", as.character(hour))) %>%
  select(hour, count, duration)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   hour     count duration
#>   <chr>    <int> <drtn>  
#> 1 06:00:00     0  5 mins 
#> 2 07:00:00    13 60 mins 
#> 3 08:00:00     8 60 mins 
#> 4 09:00:00     0 60 mins 
#> 5 10:00:00    11 60 mins 
#> 6 11:00:00    10 60 mins 
#> 7 12:00:00     7 60 mins 
#> 8 13:00:00     0 24 mins
```

Comment: Thank you @Allan! This ALMOST works for me, but there is one small problem that is causing the "duration" column to list "-415 mins, -355 mins, -295 mins, -235 mins, -175 mins, -115 mins, -55 mins, 5 mins" (sorry, I don't know how to display it better than that in a comment) instead of the correct results your example shows. I've narrowed the problem down to somewhere in the last mutate command in your code, so hopefully I can figure it out from there.